# Find and unmark marked files using string compare?

Tags: rename, string

In bash, I have a script that a uses while loop to copy files in a certain folder to various different directories. After each file is copied, I've written

```
mv $dir/$file $dir/_$file
```

using `_` in the file's prefix to mark that it's been copied. (`$dir` is where the files are copied from.) At the end of the loop, the script lists the unmarked files to show which ones have not been copied.

I came across a small conflict where some files get copied more than once to different directories, but it cannot copy the file again because its name has been changed.

I was thinking of using `if [ $file -eq $dir/_$file ]` but no good.
What's a simple way to check a directory for `"_$file"` given `"$file"`?

If there is a better method of doing all of this, that would be swell.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, using this:

```
[ -f $dir/_$file ]
```

or

```
if [ -f $dir/_$file ]; then
```

to simply check the existence of a file with the particular prefix. Quite simple, I made it more difficult than needed.

Sometimes, I don't know whether or not to use quotation whenever referencing variables.

Answer (score 0):

Given a file which is expanded to by `$filename`:

```
if [[ -f "dir/_${filename}" ]]; then
    echo "The prefixed copy exists."
else
    echo "The prefixed copy does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: What's difference between using double and single set of brackets? `if [[ -f "dir/_${filename}" ]]` or `if [ -f $dir/_$file ]`

Comment: `bash`'s "extended test" construct, identified by double-square-bracket enclosure, is a superset of the older, more fragile single-bracket enclosure.  It is designed to work around accidental errors and "do the right thing" for things which would be an error with `test` or `[`.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS

Comment: so, the double-square-bracket is the safer method when it comes to testing?

Comment: In short, yes.  If you're using a `bash` script, there is no reason to ever _not_ use extended test constructs in place of the older flavor.  If you are aiming for portability to other shells (e. g. `sh`), though, then using the more brittle `test` or `[` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the answers, but I've put my answer too. Maybe it's will be helpful for somebody.

```
#!/bin/sh

filename="file"
directory="bash_test"

if [ "$filename" = "$(basename $directory/_$filename|tr -d ^_)" ]
then
    echo "Prefix exists."
else
    echo "Prefix not exists."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The test with `-eq` would fail as the arguments are not integers (`-eq` tests for arithmetic equivalence of two integers).

What you probably want to do is to check whether the underscored name is already taken by something else, not just a regular file.

You may do this with

```
if [ -e "$dir/_$file" ]; then
    printf 'The name "%s" already exists in directory %s\n' "_$file" "$dir"
fi
```

You would need to double quote `$dir/_$file` as I have shown above, or as `"$dir"/_"$file"` (as long as both `$dir` and `$file` are quoted). This avoids word splitting on the value of the variables, which in turn avoids a runtime syntax error if one or both of them for some reason contained whitespace characters.  It also avoids invoking filename generation (globbing) on the directory and file name.

I've used the `-e` test because I assume that you'd also like to know if there, for example, is a *directory* with the underscored name in the `$dir` directory.